# How can I contain my muliple <Text> inside the View?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have balance and the symbol of money I want to show them inside same view but the value showing on the money symbol, How can I solve this ? This is my code

```
<View style={styles.balanceWrapper}>
    <View style={[styles.balance,{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-around',flex:1}]}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#7980c9',fontFamily:'made-evolve-light',marginTop:-25,marginLeft:15 }}>Balance</Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={[styles.balanceDis,{marginRight:15,flex:0.8}]}>12345.12345678</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.balanceDis,{marginRight:15,flex:0.2,}]}>SIN</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

I cannot set the styles, how should my style be ? I want to show two of them in the same line and if the balance value is long, I used a numberOfLines but I could not work it right.

This is how it looks:

[image: myimage]

Comment: Try `{ flex: 1 }` as style to scale the text only within container and display ellipsis. Please share the full code or create a CodeSandBox project, so that we can help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try using the ellipsizeMode prop thats supposed to work with the numberOfLines prop to determine what part of the string will be cut?, in you case I believe you are looking for:

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail' style={[styles.balanceDis,{marginRight:15,flex:0.8}]}>12345.12345678</Text>
```

Also from the docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

[image]

This might also be giving you some problems since you text elements are nested so I would check that out as well.

And finally there's some extra styles you are not showing on your code 'styles.balanceDis' it might be helpful to show this ones as well to see if something there might be causing it or as the above comment mentioned post a codeSandbox project.

I was going to post this as a comment but I'm missing 2 rep to do that, anyhow, I hope it helps.